# android app can install on android device, but can't install on android rom

Tags: android, rom

the logcat said java.language.runtimeException:unable to create service com.***.*** :java lang...
error log information :
https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pymeZ6QdUGZzUqx38dpn7dxRrSafz6o7MwL5rZ6L542cokVb12N4KZPqsLBKD8m42fbqOJdzn0ygh5B6tEqzvmg/error.jpg?download&psid=1

Comment: please paste here the entire stacktrace. the important part is trimmed in your photo.

Comment: that's the question, I can't get the entire stacktrace infromation, since I just give my apk file to another company,they report that errror to me, that's  whole I know.

Comment: we won't be able to help you without the entire stacktrace, and the source code where your app crashes.